# index.js cannot get / when accessing localhost:5000

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
const FatSecret = require('./fatsecret');
const fatAPI = new FatSecret('50cee42503b74b4693e3dc6fccff8725','2755697297a84ac5a702461b166e71f6');
// Express webhook
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000
app.use( express.json() );
app.post('/', (req, res) => processWebhook( req, res ));
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${ PORT }`));
var processWebhook = function( request, response ){
if (request.body.result) {
processV1Request(request, response);
} else if (request.body.queryResult) {
processV2Request(request, response);
} else {
console.log('Invalid Request');
return response.status(400).end('Invalid Webhook Request (expecting v1 or v2 webhook request)');
  }
}
```

I'm trying to access localhost:5000 but I get error cannot get /
I'm using API from [here](https://github.com/dftec-es/dialogflow-fatsecret)

Comment: Time to generate a new API key.

Comment: You do not have route for GET / request, you can try add this snippet to your code to understand How does it works.  `...app.use( express.json() ); app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!'))`

Answer (score 1):

Dude, if what you say is true, you are trying to GET that endpoint, but your route is a POST:

```
app.post('/', (req, res) => processWebhook( req, res ));
```

Try:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => processWebhook( req, res ));
```

Nevertheless I think you really do want to POST (since you need a body). If you are testing your app as it stands, make sure you are POSTing!

Comment: Invalid Webhook Request (expecting v1 or v2 webhook request)

Comment: I think you are confused.  If you need to do a post, and you probably do need to POST to pass a request body, then do a post.  So no GET, and pass the right key in on the body.  Your testing tool should do a POST and not a GET.